# How do I set up a massive spider glue trap like the one found on Reddit a week ago?

Tags: pest-control

The thread details are at http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/kdmd2/thought_id_check_the_spider_trap_i_stuck_in_my/.

Does anyone know what sort of glue trap I should buy? And what are the best locations to set these traps up? Should it be under the drawer? In a corner? Or what else? Also - should there be a cover over the trap?

Are there also glue traps that work on the walls? (maybe even for spiders that go upside down?) And also - do they work better than the Victor Poison-Free Magnet traps? (that have walls that might divert possible spiders)

Images attached below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My problem is camel crickets more than spiders.

I personally put the glue boards near the wall anyplace along the basement wall that gets wet the most often, and near the door to the outside.  Basically, it's the places where I've seen evidence of them, pushed up against the wall.  Under sinks and places of moisture tend to be the best locations in my experience.

As for where to get them ... um ... there's a website posted on the picture, but it looks like their catalog is more geared towards stores buying a display worth of product rather than just a few of 'em.  I've seen glue boards for sale at the local Home Depot, and I've gotten them at online before.

As for the question of cover, there are some that are designed so that it gets folded up into a little triangular tent-like shape, with the glue on the inside.

Answer (score 2):

They're just glue traps. Typically used for mice. Not the most humane way to catch mice, but they work. You can find them at any big-box store.

If you have pets in the house, be careful...this stuff will NOT COME OUT of fur and you end up having to shave the pet to get the things out. ;)

Comment: There are two types of glue traps ... the ones for rodents tends to be the more tray-like one with a really sticky goo in it.  The ones for insects tend to be the more a thin film, like contact cement.  (although, I've seen ones for rodents that were the folm ones).  The rodent ones tend to be a plastic tray, and can't be folded up into the little tent-like structure.  (the film ones can't always ... they'll have slots on each end, opposing each other, so that you can clip it into the tent shape).

Comment: I've seen both marketed as mouse traps...that said, I live up north so we likely don't have the same spider issues as further south.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently a fan of Tom Cat brand glue boards, there small enough to fit in out of the way places and so far have minimized the spider population that normally I find in my basement apartment. On first trying them the trap was soo covered with spiders it was shocking. And now about every 6 months I replace them, best places seem to be behind trash cans, corner by fridge, and one on each side of my sliding glass door.

They typically catch about 30 spiders and insects combined. Though in there first use one trap may have had that many. They catch the baby spiders as well, the ones too small to see from a distance.

For me they are a huge success with only maybe every once in a great while finding a spider. I don't aggressively kill them unless they are poisonous or I can't tell. I still want them around as I have no problems with ants or other insects which I'm sure they help control.